# How to check same value in two integer Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2012, console

i can't find same values in two integer arrays. Here is my code

```
int[] array1 = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

How to check same value?

I tried;

```
IEnumerable<int> k = (from d1 in array1
                              select d1).Intersect(from d2 in array2
                                                   select d2).ToList();
foreach (var item in k)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

It is true, but i don't want to do this way.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of other way are you looking for? You have a solution that works, what is wrong with that approach?

Comment: So... you want to rewrite the code of Intersect?  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: Just simplify it: `array1.Inersect(array2).ToList()`.

Comment: Let's say I'm now at the beginning. Then how do you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a 1 liner:

```
array1.Intersect(array2).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Comment: You can also just do `.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)` at the end